# a letter tree in C

Tags: c, tree, letters

I'd like to store some data associated to words composed of simple ascii letters (a-Z)
The goal is to retrieve very quickly the data associated to a word in a future parsing.

I though about the following structure:

```
struct Foo {
  Foo *letter[26];
  void *data;
};
```

Thus, it is possible to go down through the "letter tree" while parsing a word in a string and get the associated data.

```
"foo" => ['f' node] -> ['o' node] -> ['o' node]
```

The problem is the size of the entire tree if I got many words.

Is there a way to reduce the size of the tree without losing performances?

Comment: -1 from me, it's impossible to talk about performance improvement without seeing the actuall data sets used.

Comment: Is your goal similar to the general uses of a [Radix Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) ?

Comment: Notice the final parts of the trees for "foo" and "boo" are the same. By reusing the common endings you reduce a lot the size of the trees :)

Comment: Take a look at [Adding word to Trie structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674617/adding-word-to-trie-structure-dictionary/).  The memory allocation there is a little more complex (it allocates 27 pointers instead of using 26 pointers in a array in the structure) and it stores the word in lieu of your `data` field, but otherwise, it seems very similar.

Comment: yes, a Radix Tree is great, thanks to all of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describeing is called `trie`. A [compact radix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_prefix_tree) is more compact.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using a tree instead of storing words in a hash table?  These will tend to use a bit more memory, but will give you near constant time performance for table lookups.

Comment: a hash table needs the entire word to get the associated data. With a radix tree, I can parse my word (in a string) letter by letter and stop as soon I don't find an appropriate node.